# confluent_kafka.error.ValueSerializationError: KafkaError{code=_VALUE_SERIALIZATION,val=-161 : ValueError

Tags: avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-kafka-python, fastavro

I am new bee to python and trying to use 'confluent_kafka' for avro message produce.
Using 'confluent_kafka.schema_registry.avro.AvroSerializer' for the same
(referred : https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/examples/avro_producer.py)

It works for simple avro schema with dict(json converted to dict) input, but for below sample schema I am getting error :

Schema :

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Envelope",
    "namespace": "CoreOLTPEvents.dbo.Event",
    "fields": [{
        "name": "before",
        "type": ["null", {
            "type": "record",
            "name": "Value",
            "fields": [{
                "name": "EventId",
                "type": "long"
            }, {
                "name": "CameraId",
                "type": ["null", "long"],
                "default": null
            }],
            "connect.name": "CoreOLTPEvents.dbo.Event.Value"
        }],
        "default": null
    }, {
        "name": "after",
        "type": ["null", "Value"],
        "default": null
    }, {
        "name": "source",
        "type": {
            "type": "record",
            "name": "Source",
            "namespace": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver",
            "fields": [{
                "name": "version",
                "type": "string"
            }, {
                "name": "connector",
                "type": "string"
            }],
            "connect.name": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.Source"
        }
    }, {
        "name": "op",
        "type": "string"
    }],
    "connect.name": "CoreOLTPEvents.dbo.Event.Envelope"
}
```

Input Json :

```
{
    "after": null,
    "before": {
        "CoreOLTPEvents.dbo.Event.Value" : {
        "EventId": 1111111111,
        "CameraId": 222222222
    }
    },
    "source": {
        "version": "InitialLoad",
        "connector": "sqlserver"
    },
    "op": "C"
}
```

Error :
`ValueError: {'CoreOLTPEvents.dbo.Event.Value': {'EventId': 1111111111, 'CameraId': 222222222}} (type <class 'dict'>) do not match ['null', {'connect.name': 'CoreOLTPEvents.dbo.Event.Value', 'type': 'record', 'name': 'CoreOLTPEvents.dbo.Event.Value', 'fields': [{'name': 'EventId', 'type': 'long'}, {'default': None, 'name': 'CameraId', 'type': ['null', 'long']}]}] on field before`

'before' field type is union (['null',record]), if I change it to only record (remove union) then it works fine.
But I need to adjust my input such a way that it works for given schema.

(Note : I am reading json input using 'json.load(json_file)' so it gives dict output)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Update :
Actual large schema :

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Envelope",
    "namespace": "CoreOLTPEvents.dbo.Event",
    "fields": [{
        "name": "before",
        "type": ["null", {
            "type": "record",
            "name": "Value",
            "fields": [{
                "name": "EventId",
                "type": "long"
            }, {
                "name": "CameraId",
                "type": ["null", "long"],
                "default": null
            }, {
                "name": "SiteId",
                "type": ["null", "long"],
                "default": null
            }, {
                "name": "VehicleId",
                "type": ["null", "long"],
                "default": null
            }, {
                "name": "EventReviewStatusID",
                "type": "int"
            }, {
                "name": "EventTypeId",
                "type": ["null", "int"],
                "default": null
            }, {
                "name": "EventDateTime",
                "type": ["null", {
                    "type": "string",
                    "connect.name": "net.smartdrive.converters.SmartdriveEventDateFieldConverter"
                }],
                "default": null
            }, {
                "name": "FTPUploadDateTime",
                "type": {
                    "type": "long",
                    "connect.version": 1,
                    "connect.name": "io.debezium.time.Timestamp"
                }
            }, {
                "name": "CAMFileName",
                "type": "string"
            }, {
                "name": "KeypadEntryCode",
                "type": ["null", "string"],
                "default": null
            }, {
                "name": "IsActive",
                "type": {
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "connect.default": true
                },
                "default": true
            }, {
                "name": "Flagged",
                "type": "boolean"
            }, {
                "name": "EventTitle",
                "type": ["null", "string"],
                "default": null
            }, {
                "name": "CreatedBy",
                "type": "long"
            }, {
                "name": "CreatedDate",
                "type": {
                    "type": "long",
                    "connect.version": 1,
                    "connect.name": "io.debezium.time.Timestamp"
                }
            }, {
                "name": "ModifiedBy",
                "type": "long"
            }, {
                "name": "ModifiedDate",
                "type": {
                    "type": "long",
                    "connect.version": 1,
                    "connect.name": "io.debezium.time.Timestamp"
                }
            }, {
                "name": "ReReviewAnalysis",
                "type": ["null", "string"],
                "default": null
            }, {
                "name": "LegacyEventId",
                "type": ["null", "long"],
                "default": null
            }, {
                "name": "TripId",
                "type": ["null", "long"],
                "default": null
            }, {
                "name": "FileVersion",
                "type": ["null", "string"],
                "default": null
            }, {
                "name": "EventNumber",
                "type": ["null", "string"],
                "default": null
            }, {
                "name": "Latitude",
                "type": ["null", {
                    "type": "bytes",
                    "scale": 10,
                    "precision": 13,
                    "connect.version": 1,
                    "connect.parameters": {
                        "scale": "10",
                        "connect.decimal.precision": "13"
                    },
                    "connect.name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal",
                    "logicalType": "decimal"
                }],
                "default": null
            }, {
                "name": "Longitude",
                "type": ["null", {
                    "type": "bytes",
                    "scale": 10,
                    "precision": 13,
                    "connect.version": 1,
                    "connect.parameters": {
                        "scale": "10",
                        "connect.decimal.precision": "13"
                    },
                    "connect.name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal",
                    "logicalType": "decimal"
                }],
                "default": null
            }, {
                "name": "GeoAddressId",
                "type": ["null", "long"],
                "default": null
            }, {
                "name": "ReviewedEventId",
                "type": ["null", "long"],
                "default": null
            }, {
                "name": "VideoStatus",
                "type": {
                    "type": "int",
                    "connect.default": 0
                },
                "default": 0
            }, {
                "name": "PredictionImportance",
                "type": ["null", {
                    "type": "bytes",
                    "scale": 10,
                    "precision": 15,
                    "connect.version": 1,
                    "connect.parameters": {
                        "scale": "10",
                        "connect.decimal.precision": "15"
                    },
                    "connect.name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal",
                    "logicalType": "decimal"
                }],
                "default": null
            }, {
                "name": "FlaggedBy",
                "type": ["null", "long"],
                "default": null
            }, {
                "name": "FlaggedDate",
                "type": ["null", {
                    "type": "long",
                    "connect.version": 1,
                    "connect.name": "io.debezium.time.Timestamp"
                }],
                "default": null
            }, {
                "name": "TriggerTypeId",
                "type": ["null", "int"],
                "default": null
            }, {
                "name": "VideoDeleteDate",
                "type": ["null", {
                    "type": "long",
                    "connect.version": 1,
                    "connect.name": "io.debezium.time.Timestamp"
                }],
                "default": null
            }, {
                "name": "MetadataDeleteDate",
                "type": ["null", {
                    "type": "long",
                    "connect.version": 1,
                    "connect.name": "io.debezium.time.Timestamp"
                }],
                "default": null
            }, {
                "name": "RetentionStatus",
                "type": {
                    "type": "int",
                    "connect.default": 0,
                    "connect.type": "int16"
                },
                "default": 0
            }, {
                "name": "PartnerTriggerId",
                "type": ["null", "int"],
                "default": null
            }, {
                "name": "CoachingStateId",
                "type": {
                    "type": "int",
                    "connect.default": 0,
                    "connect.type": "int16"
                },
                "default": 0
            }, {
                "name": "EventKudoHistoryId",
                "type": ["null", "int"],
                "default": null
            }],
            "connect.name": "CoreOLTPEvents.dbo.Event.Value"
        }],
        "default": null
    }, {
        "name": "after",
        "type": ["null", "Value"],
        "default": null
    }, {
        "name": "source",
        "type": {
            "type": "record",
            "name": "Source",
            "namespace": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver",
            "fields": [{
                "name": "version",
                "type": "string"
            }, {
                "name": "connector",
                "type": "string"
            }, {
                "name": "name",
                "type": "string"
            }, {
                "name": "ts_ms",
                "type": "long"
            }, {
                "name": "snapshot",
                "type": [{
                    "type": "string",
                    "connect.version": 1,
                    "connect.parameters": {
                        "allowed": "true,last,false"
                    },
                    "connect.default": "false",
                    "connect.name": "io.debezium.data.Enum"
                }, "null"],
                "default": "false"
            }, {
                "name": "db",
                "type": "string"
            }, {
                "name": "schema",
                "type": "string"
            }, {
                "name": "table",
                "type": "string"
            }, {
                "name": "change_lsn",
                "type": ["null", "string"],
                "default": null
            }, {
                "name": "commit_lsn",
                "type": ["null", "string"],
                "default": null
            }, {
                "name": "event_serial_no",
                "type": ["null", "long"],
                "default": null
            }],
            "connect.name": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.Source"
        }
    }, {
        "name": "op",
        "type": "string"
    }, {
        "name": "ts_ms",
        "type": ["null", "long"],
        "default": null
    }, {
        "name": "transaction",
        "type": ["null", {
            "type": "record",
            "name": "ConnectDefault",
            "namespace": "io.confluent.connect.avro",
            "fields": [{
                "name": "id",
                "type": "string"
            }, {
                "name": "total_order",
                "type": "long"
            }, {
                "name": "data_collection_order",
                "type": "long"
            }]
        }],
        "default": null
    }],
    "connect.name": "CoreOLTPEvents.dbo.Event.Envelope"
}
```

Input for large schema :

```
{
    "before": null,
    "after": {
        "EventId": 1234566,
        "CameraId": 2233,
        "SiteId": 111,
        "VehicleId": 45587,
        "EventReviewStatusID": 10,
        "EventTypeId": 123,
        "EventDateTime": "2015-01-02T01:30:29Z",
        "FTPUploadDateTime": 1420193330590,
        "CAMFileName": "XYZ",
        "KeypadEntryCode": "0",
        "IsActive": false,
        "Flagged": false,
        "EventTitle": null,
        "CreatedBy": 1,
        "CreatedDate": 1420191120730,
        "ModifiedBy": 1,
        "ModifiedDate": 1577871185680,
        "ReReviewAnalysis": null,
        "LegacyEventId": null,
        "TripId": 3382,
        "FileVersion": "2.2",
        "EventNumber": "AAAA-BBBB",
        "Latitude": "UU9elrA=",
        "Longitude": "/ueZUeFw",
        "GeoAddressId": null,
        "ReviewedEventId": 129411077,
        "VideoStatus": 4,
        "PredictionImportance": 0.1402457539,
        "FlaggedBy": null,
        "FlaggedDate": null,
        "TriggerTypeId": 322,
        "VideoDeleteDate": 1422783120000,
        "MetadataDeleteDate": 1577871120000,
        "RetentionStatus": 15,
        "PartnerTriggerId": null,
        "CoachingStateId": 0,
        "EventKudoHistoryId": null

    },
    "source": {
        "version": "Final",
        "connector": "sqlserver",
        "name": "CoreOLTP",
        "ts_ms": 1615813992548,
        "snapshot": "false",
        "db": "CoreOLTP",
        "schema": "dbo",
        "table": "xyz",
        "change_lsn": null,
        "commit_lsn": null,
        "event_serial_no": null
    },
    "op": "C",
    "ts_ms": 1615813992548,
    "transaction": null
}
```

Error :

```
confluent_kafka.error.ValueSerializationError: KafkaError{code=_VALUE_SERIALIZATION,val=-161,str="{'EventId': 129411077, 'CameraId': 46237, 'SiteId': 2148, 'VehicleId': 45587, 'EventReviewStatusID': 10, 'EventTypeId': 247, 'EventDateTime': '2015-01-02T01:30:29Z', 'FTPUploadDateTime': 1420191120590, 'CAMFileName': 'JD2BC02120150102013029ER.SDE', 'KeypadEntryCode': '0', 'IsActive': False, 'Flagged': False, 'EventTitle': None, 'CreatedBy': 1, 'CreatedDate': 1420191120730, 'ModifiedBy': 1, 'ModifiedDate': 1577871185680, 'ReReviewAnalysis': None, 'LegacyEventId': None, 'TripId': 3382, 'FileVersion': '2.2', 'EventNumber': 'WSHX-8QQ2', 'Latitude': 'UU9elrA=', 'Longitude': '/ueZUeFw', 'GeoAddressId': None, 'ReviewedEventId': 129411077, 'VideoStatus': 4, 'PredictionImportance': 0.1402457539, 'FlaggedBy': None, 'FlaggedDate': None, 'TriggerTypeId': 322, 'VideoDeleteDate': 1422783120000, 'MetadataDeleteDate': 1577871120000, 'RetentionStatus': 15, 'PartnerTriggerId': None, 'CoachingStateId': 0, 'EventKudoHistoryId': None} (type <class 'dict'>) do not match ['null', 'CoreOLTPEvents.dbo.Event.Value'] on field after"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change your input so that the `before` field doesn't have the namespace. So it needs to look like this:

```
{
    "after": null,
    "before": {
        "EventId": 1111111111,
        "CameraId": 222222222
    },
    "source": {
        "version": "InitialLoad",
        "connector": "sqlserver"
    },
    "op": "C"
}
```

The original input you had looked like it was trying to be JSON encoded avro because the field `before` had the `CoreOLTPEvents.dbo.Event.Value` namespace. However, I'm guessing it must have been hand crafted because `CameraId` should have been specified as `{"long": 222222222}` rather than just `222222222`.

If you do actually have Avro encoded JSON (from the result of some other process or something) then you you could use something like `fastavro.json_reader` to read in that file and it will create the correct memory representation (that doesn't include the type information for union fields).

UPDATE:

To figure out what the problem is with the full schema and full data, I first loaded the two objects using `json.load` and then used `fastavro.validate(record, schema)` The output from that is a stacktrace that ends with this:

```py
fastavro._validate_common.ValidationError: [
  "CoreOLTPEvents.dbo.Event.Envelope.after is <{'EventId': 1234566, 'CameraId': 2233, 'SiteId': 111, 'VehicleId': 45587, 'EventReviewStatusID': 10, 'EventTypeId': 123, 'EventDateTime': '2015-01-02T01:30:29Z', 'FTPUploadDateTime': 1420193330590, 'CAMFileName': 'XYZ', 'KeypadEntryCode': '0', 'IsActive': False, 'Flagged': False, 'EventTitle': None, 'CreatedBy': 1, 'CreatedDate': 1420191120730, 'ModifiedBy': 1, 'ModifiedDate': 1577871185680, 'ReReviewAnalysis': None, 'LegacyEventId': None, 'TripId': 3382, 'FileVersion': '2.2', 'EventNumber': 'AAAA-BBBB', 'Latitude': 'UU9elrA=', 'Longitude': '/ueZUeFw', 'GeoAddressId': None, 'ReviewedEventId': 129411077, 'VideoStatus': 4, 'PredictionImportance': 0.1402457539, 'FlaggedBy': None, 'FlaggedDate': None, 'TriggerTypeId': 322, 'VideoDeleteDate': 1422783120000, 'MetadataDeleteDate': 1577871120000, 'RetentionStatus': 15, 'PartnerTriggerId': None, 'CoachingStateId': 0, 'EventKudoHistoryId': None}> of type <class 'dict'> expected null",
  "CoreOLTPEvents.dbo.Event.Value.Latitude is <UU9elrA=> of type <class 'str'> expected null",
  "CoreOLTPEvents.dbo.Event.Value.Latitude is <UU9elrA=> of type <class 'str'> expected {'scale': 10, 'precision': 13, 'connect.version': 1, 'connect.parameters': {'scale': '10', 'connect.decimal.precision': '13'}, 'connect.name': 'org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal', 'logicalType': 'decimal', 'type': 'bytes'}"
]
```

So that is trying to tell us that there is 3 potential problems. The first is that the value in `after` doesn't match `null`, but we can ignore that because we don't want `after` to match `null`.

The later two problems are the actual problem. It says that the value of `Latitude` is the string `UU9elrA=`, but that doesn't match either `null` or `bytes`. The string here looks base64 encoded, so maybe you have some code that decodes that to bytes and if so then maybe the actual problem is something else, but if so then I think you should be able to use `fastavro.validate` to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks @Scott . Yes this worked for me later when I removed that namespace and tried.
Actually what I posted here and tried is small portion of big schema and input for that.

When I am trying with actual large schema and input for that, I am again getting same error, that looks quite strange.

I have edited my original question to post the actual large schema and input json

Comment: I updated my answer to address the questions regarding the full schema.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Scott.
This is what I was looking for ! Yes Lat Long fields are the issue.

Comment: do we think the issue is that Debezium wraps the value as a class int instead of a real int?